# Tensorflow: tf.random_uniform vs tf.constant

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I keep running out of memory with tensorflow. To see what is going on, I tried to do a simple matrix addition: `C = A + B`, where `A` and `B` are random matrices of size (15000,15000)

I'm using this very simple example code here, except I modified it a bit:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/5_MultiGPU/multigpu_basics.py

Here is my modification:

```
import sys 
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime

device_name = sys.argv[1]  # Choose device from cmd line. Options: gpu or cpu
shape = int(sys.argv[2])
if device_name == "gpu":
    device_name = "/gpu:0"
else:
    device_name = "/cpu:0"


with tf.device(device_name):
    a = np.random.rand(shape,shape)
    b = np.random.rand(shape,shape)
    sum_operation = tf.add(a,b)


startTime = datetime.now()
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as session:
    result = session.run(sum_operation)
    print(result)

# It can be hard to see the results on the terminal with lots of output -- add some newlines to improve readability.
print("\n" * 5)
print("Shape:", shape, "Device:", device_name)
print("Time taken:", datetime.now() - startTime)

print("\n" * 5)
```

I ran: `python test_file.py gpu 15000`

Why do you think I receive this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_file.py", line 28, in <module>
    result = session.run(sum_operation)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 997, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1139, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1117, in _run_fn
    self._extend_graph()
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1161, in _extend_graph
    add_shapes=self._add_shapes)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2324, in _as_graph_def
    raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.")
ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.
```

I've also tried using:

```
with tf.device(device_name):
    a = np.random.rand(shape,shape)
    b = np.random.rand(shape,shape)
    A = tf.constant(a)
    B = tf.constant(b)
    sum_operation = tf.add(A,B)
```

No luck. Same error. I'm probably doing something wrong.

But to be specific -- I *am* trying to compare theano speed vs tensorflow speed with some of my more complex computations (with a much larger dataset size). So, I am ultimately trying to input the same random matrix to both theano and tensorflow, and I guess this approach isn't working.

Why does `tf.random_uniform` work but the `tf.constant` approach doesn't?

Comment: tf.constant embeds value into the graph (2GB) limit, whereas tf.random_uniform allocates it dynamically using whatever memory you have (no limit)